# Issue with jQuery window event triggering on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with `$(window).scroll` event on mobile phones. It is working perfectly on the desktop views. Please help me to make it trigger on mobile phones also. My Used code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
alert($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

I had also tried to disable overflow on mobile phones. Like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px)
{
html, body
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;overflow:hidden;   
}
}
```

But still not getting the alert on mobile. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with the **CSS** you have given.....

change like this.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px)
{
  html, body
  {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow:scroll;
  }
}
```

The CSS styles make the **html** and the **body** of your ***Document fits Exactly into the Window***. So *If you even Scroll the document*, the **Document is being scrolled** ***but not the Window*** (which wraps your HTML document).

Your CSS tries to make the website Mobile-Responsive..... For that you can do the followings.

- add this`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">` tag to the **Head** of **HTML**.
- change the **CSS** as I given.

Comment: Still not worked. Actually meta viewport was already included into my page. Window event not triggering on mobile.

Comment: If that works on Desktop and not on Mobile phones, please check with some other browsers and tell me......

Comment: I tested on mozilla and opera mini too. Same issue arising.:-(

Comment: I know it is occuring because of overflow on mobiles. But using overflow scroll property as suggested above and still the same issue persist. Don't know why.

Comment: Try this as an experimentation, Try to **remove** the ***Media CSS query for small devices*** and then try it on the mobile..... This helps us to come to a clear conclusion.....

This issue is taking more time than usual, I appreciate your patience....

Comment: I already did it bro. :-P Every possible thing i tried but reached at no solution yet. So for the mean time, I am using link pagination instead of scroll down. But i am eagerly looking for its solution. It's really a great headache for me right now. By the way, Thanx for your time to help me.:-)

Comment: Buddy, please try the scroll event on your body like `$("body").scroll(function() {}) ;`

If that works, we have arrived at the solution.

If this too doesn't help, please comment the URL of the site.(i hope the site is already hosted)